# Possible SQL backup via joomla?

Tags: joomla

Due to a client's hosting being inaccessible on my reseller account, its not possible to access his cpanel to make a backup of a SQL database. However a backup of his website still works and lets us access joomla administrator as normal and has all the relevant up to date users from the sql db(so the sql db is still online). However as we cannot access the actual Phpmyadmin to make a backup, is there anyway to back it up through joomla?

Comment: Check the joomla extension directory for several options: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup

Answer (score 4):

With [Akeeba Backup](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-security/backup/1606) the process should be quite easy. Just install the joomla extension and perform the backup.

Answer (score 0):

that is possible but you first download  Akeeba backup tools than you take back up and one more link give you thats you are problem solve easily

http://docs.joomla.org/Backup

first you referred this site than you go head